# BitConvert.Int32, Shouldn´t this be faster?

Tags: c#

I am trying to improve the speed of BitConvert, or rather, an alternative way.

So here is the code i thought was supposed to be faster :

```
    bsize = ms.length
    int index = 0;
    byte[] target = new byte[intsize];
    target[index++] = (byte)bsize;
    target[index++] = (byte)(bsize >> 8);
    target[index++] = (byte)(bsize >> 16);
    target[index] = (byte)(bsize >> 24);
```

And well the BitConvert code:

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(bsize)
```

And well, it wasn´t faster, it was alot slower from my tests, more than twice as slow.

So why is it slower?
And is there a way to improve the speed?

EDIT:

```
BitConvert = 5068 Ticks

OtherMethod above: 12847 Ticks
```

EDIT 2: My Benchmark code:

```
private unsafe void ExecuteBenchmark(int samplingSize = 100000)
    {
        // run the Garbage collector
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        // log start
        Console.WriteLine("Benchmark started");

        // start timer
        var t = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                for (int i = 0; i < samplingSize; i++)
                {

                }
        }
        // stop timer
        t.Stop();
        // log ending
        Console.WriteLine("Execute1 time = " + t.ElapsedTicks + " ticks");
    }
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Why is it slower, and is there a way to make it faster than bitconvert. :)

Comment: I would guess that if there was a "faster" way, it would already be implemented in the BitConverter code. In other words, the frawework developers are pretty darn smart.

Comment: Perhaps, but what about the overhead, as i guess calling the BitConvert should get some overhead, making a performance loss (even if small)

Comment: BitConverter only adds arguments checks and a modulo 4 check to find out if it can optimize the conversion. After that the implementation is `unsafe  *(int*)(&target[0]);`

Comment: @user2587718: Your code is what is commonly called a "[naive implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257331/how-do-i-explain-what-a-naive-implementation-is)", i.e. the first obvious thing that comes to mind when someone asks you how to implement something. It shouldn't be surprising that the naive implementation is slower.

Comment: question is not why BitConverter is faster, the question is why do you think that your implementation is supposed to be faster.

Comment: Well, i read here some statistics, and saw that bitshifting was extremely fast, and they compared it to BitConvert. But i must have misunderstood it somehow:S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is slower, because `BitConverter` uses `unsafe` code which operates on pointers:

```
public unsafe static byte[] GetBytes(int value)
{
    byte[] array = new byte[4];
    fixed (byte* ptr = array)
    {
        *(int*)ptr = value;
    }
    return array;
}
```

And back to `int`:

```
public unsafe static int ToInt32(byte[] value, int startIndex)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.value);
    }
    if ((ulong)startIndex >= (ulong)((long)value.Length))
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.startIndex, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_Index);
    }
    if (startIndex > value.Length - 4)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Arg_ArrayPlusOffTooSmall);
    }
    int result;
    if (startIndex % 4 == 0)
    {
        result = *(int*)(&value[startIndex]);
    }
    else
    {
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            result = ((int)(*(&value[startIndex])) | (int)(&value[startIndex])[(IntPtr)1 / 1] << 8 | (int)(&value[startIndex])[(IntPtr)2 / 1] << 16 | (int)(&value[startIndex])[(IntPtr)3 / 1] << 24);
        }
        else
        {
            result = ((int)(*(&value[startIndex])) << 24 | (int)(&value[startIndex])[(IntPtr)1 / 1] << 16 | (int)(&value[startIndex])[(IntPtr)2 / 1] << 8 | (int)(&value[startIndex])[(IntPtr)3 / 1]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use the code inline, but it won´t work.
Shouldn´t i be able to just use int result, and then use Value = my byte[], startIndex = 0. Cause get many errors like : You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer

Comment: The OP asked about converting integer to byte array, not byte array to integer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, measuring the speed of such a tiny amount of code is going to be error-prone. Posting your benchmark might give more answers.

But my guess is that on platforms supporting it (like x86), BitConverter probably does a single bounds check and an unaligned write into `target` rather than 3 shifts, 4 bounds checks, and 4 writes. It may end up completely inlined, alleviating all call overhead.

Comment: Well i did many tests, and BitConvert got around 5k ticks.
while the other method got around 12k ticks, so the difference was quite big.

I am using x64 if it matters.

Comment: @user2587718 - He means, show us how you *measured* it.  You should be  using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` for this, and you should probably measure in a for loop with a few thousand iterations.  If you used `DateTime.Now`, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I am doing it with StopWatch in a for loop with 10000. So it does it 10000 times, else the ticks are so small. And it´s always pretty much the same results.