# VB Script modify XML File Nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript

This is a sample XML document contents:

```
<row>
    <RaceNumber>131</RaceNumber>
    <title1>Cedar County Board of Supervisors</title1>
    <PrecintPercent>100</PrecintPercent>
    <Winner>5149</Winner>
    <WinningVotes>6213</WinningVotes>
    <WinningParty>R</WinningParty>
    <Winner1>Jeff Kaufmann</Winner1>
    <WinnerSelected>1</WinnerSelected>
    <WinnerPercent>28</WinnerPercent>
    <Loser>5148</Loser>
    <LosingVotes>4628</LosingVotes>
    <LosingParty>R</LosingParty>
    <Loser2>Wayne Deerberg</Loser2>
    <LoserPercent>21</LoserPercent>
    <LoserSelected>1</LoserSelected>
    <title1>Cedar County Board of Supervisors</title1>
    <PrecintPercent>100</PrecintPercent>
    <Winner>5376</Winner>
    <WinningVotes>4407</WinningVotes>
    <WinningParty>R</WinningParty>
    <Winner>JonBell</Winner>
    <WinnerSelected>1</WinnerSelected>
    <PrecintPercent>100</PrecintPercent>
    <Loser>5151</Loser>
    <LosingVotes>4141</LosingVotes>
    <LosingParty>D</LosingParty>
    <Loser>DavidShinker</Loser>
    <LoserSelected>0</LoserSelected>
    <title1>Cedar County Board of Supervisors</title1>
    <PrecintPercent>100</PrecintPercent>
    <Winner>5150</Winner>
    <WinningVotes>3167</WinningVotes>
    <WinningParty>D</WinningParty>
    <Winner>RobertPruess</Winner>
    <WinnerSelected>0</WinnerSelected>
  </row>
```

I would like to know if I could use a VB Script to modify the file to make it look like this?:

```
<row>
<ELECTION>    
    <title1>Cedar County Board of Supervisors</title1>
    <PrecintPercent>100</PrecintPercent>
    <Winner>5149</Winner>
    <WinningVotes>6213</WinningVotes>
    <WinningParty>R</WinningParty>
    <Winner1>Jeff Kaufmann</Winner1>
    <WinnerSelected>1</WinnerSelected>
    <WinnerPercent>28</WinnerPercent>
    <Loser>5148</Loser>
    <LosingVotes>4628</LosingVotes>
    <LosingParty>R</LosingParty>
    <Loser2>Wayne Deerberg</Loser2>
    <LoserPercent>21</LoserPercent>
    <LoserSelected>1</LoserSelected>
</ELECTION>
<ELECTION>
    <title1>Cedar County Board of Supervisors</title1>
    <PrecintPercent>100</PrecintPercent>
    <Winner>5376</Winner>
    <WinningVotes>4407</WinningVotes>
    <WinningParty>R</WinningParty>
    <Winner>JonBell</Winner>
    <WinnerSelected>1</WinnerSelected>
    <PrecintPercent>100</PrecintPercent>
    <Loser>5151</Loser>
    <LosingVotes>4141</LosingVotes>
    <LosingParty>D</LosingParty>
    <Loser>DavidShinker</Loser>
    <LoserSelected>0</LoserSelected>
</ELECTION>
```

Basically, I would like to write `<ELECTION>` before any tag that is titled `<title1>` and a closing tag `</ELECTION>` after any tag titled `</LoserSelected>`

Does anyone think this is possible? If so, I would like to have it write the `<ELECTION>` and `</ELECTION>` tags throughout an entire document where `<title1>` and `</LoserSelected>` would be encountered.

Any input would be great!  Thank You!

Comment: I know this is **evil**, but if your XML will always be that simple, maybe a regex to replace `<title1` to `<ELECTION><title1` and `</LoserSelected>` to `</LoserSelected></ELECTION>` would be easier.

Comment: For sure. The XML output will always be like this. However, some of the outputs will have 21 `<title1>`'s in it. I will see if I can research this. thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do what you're asking.  It will stick `<ELECTION>` before `<title1>` and `</ELECTION>` after `</LoserSelected>`

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objReadXmlFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("file.xml")
Set objNewXmlFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("file.new.xml", True)

boolSkipCloseElection = False
strPrevLine = ""

Do While Not objReadXmlFile.AtEndOfStream 
    strLine = objReadXmlFile.ReadLine()

    If InStr(1, strLine, "<title1>") Then
        If InStr(1, strPrevLine, "<ELECTION>") = 0 Then
            objNewXmlFile.Write "<ELECTION>" & vbCrLf   
        Else
            boolSkipCloseElection = True
        End If

        objNewXmlFile.Write strLine & vbCrLf
    ElseIf InStr(1, strLine, "</LoserSelected>") Then
        objNewXmlFile.Write strLine & vbCrLf   
        If boolSkipCloseElection = True Then
            boolSkipCloseElection = False           
        Else
            objNewXmlFile.Write "</ELECTION>" & vbCrLf          
        End If
    Else
        objNewXmlFile.Write strLine & vbCrLf   
    End If

    strPrevLine = strLine

Loop

objReadXmlFile.Close
objNewXmlFile.Close
```

EDIT: Will not insert those tags if they exist already.

Comment: This does exacty as you said it would. So for that- I must thank you very much! I just now need to figure out how I can correctly parse the dang XML. HA! I will now see if this is going to be a practical way to get it to work. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: Hey, what if I wanted it to ignore any records that already contained <ELECTION> and <LoserSelected>? I have ones that already have these tags and it is causing multiple nested objects. I do not know for sure if my parser will be able to Identify these nested <ELECTION>'s but I will find out when I get to the office tomorrow....or today. EEK!

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that.  Hope it works out.

Comment: You are editing an XML file with text tools. This is a foolish approach refuted a thousand times. -1

Comment: @QuickNull This is the closest I have come to getting the desired output I need! The only issue is, out of 2452 lines of XML, 6 `</LoserSelected>` tags don't get the `</ELECTION>` tag written into it. I did go through the output XML file and added the `</ELECTION>` tags into the File manually and was able to parse the XML. That's the only issue I have found with it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This (like *anything* that involves XML) is a job for tools that have been designed for XML.

XSLT is such a tool. Resist the temptation to do string replacements on XML.

```
<!-- elections.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

  <xsl:key name="kElection" match="node()[not(self::title1)]" 
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::title1[1])"
  />

  <xsl:template match="row[ELECTION]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row[not(ELECTION)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="title1" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title1">
    <ELECTION>
      <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('kElection', generate-id(.))" />
    </ELECTION>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can use the MSXML API via VBScript to execute the XSLT program, like this:

```
Dim xml, xsl, xmlOut

Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set xsl = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

xml.async = False
xsl.async = False

xml.load "your_input.xml"
xsl.load "elections.xsl"

xml.transformNodeToObject xsl, xml
xml.save "your_output.xml"
```

but simpler ways exist. You could [download the msxsl.exe tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) and to it right from the command line:

```
msxsl your_input.xml elections.xsl -o your_output.xml
```

---

Here's how the XSLT program is designed to work:

- It leaves rows alone that already contain `<ELECTION>` elements (i.e. it simply copies them to the output as they are).
- It uses an XSL key to group all nodes in the file by the first `<title1>` the precedes them. This way all elements that belong to a certain title can be retrieved together.
- It looks at all `<title1>` elements and makes a copy of them and their associated group, respectively wrapping them in `<ELECTION>` elements.

This approach is a lot safer and more versatile than doing naive string replacements.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Perhaps though, instead of insulting someone by saying an answer is foolish and naive, you use it as a way to educate someone. Seems like the point of this site.

Comment: Though testing your code with the data provided in the original question doesn't output what he's looking for.  Seems like if the <ELECTION> tag already exists, it creates <ELECTION><ELECTION></ELECTION></ELECTION> tags.

Comment: But in his input no `<ELECTION>` tags exist, nor did he say that would be the case. Of course - point in case - it would be rather easy to modify the XSLT program to account for that, and rather hard to modify a string-replace based solution.

Comment: I did not insult *you*, if at all I criticized your approach. Granted, I did it rather harshly, still it wasn't personal. I see it all too often and it really grinds my gears (by no means do I have an itchy downvote finger otherwise). Treating XML/HTML as text and doing string replacements on it is one of those "false friend" solutions that seem easy and good enough yet wreak all kinds of havoc, from character encoding glitches to clobbering input to XSS/injection vulnerabilities to impossible-to-maintain bug-ridden regex-based atrocities, so I'm a bit edgy when I see someone recommend them.

Comment: PS: Also, "naive" is not an insult. The word "naive" is commonly used to describe an overly simplistic, improvable approach in computing. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/257349/18771

Comment: I think perhaps while you were busy criticizing my approach, you missed his comment where he says that sometimes the <ELECTION> tags do exist and no special formatting/insert is required.  How would you handle that situation with your approach?

Comment: Done. (If I interpreted it correctly - the OP's statement in this regard is a bit ambiguous. I assume he did not mean he had "mixed content" rows, just ones that already have `<ELECTION>` elements and ones that don't.)

Comment: Great, thanks, regardless of your delivery, always nice to learn something new.

Comment: Hi guys! Thanks for all the comments and help.  I am having trouble parsing the data right now. It seems some of the XML tags are being nested more than I had hoped.

Yes, I actually have an XSLT stylesheet that is setting each attribute to the proper control field I need for my ticker. I will have to read over ALL the information you all left me and see if I can make great use of it. I am sure the answer is out there, but this is all pointing me in the right direction! thanks again.